# What is the difference between a tf2 static broadcast and tf2 broadcast?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-tutorials, learning-tf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following the tutorials of tf2 on ROS [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials). There are two tutorials on writing a tf2 static broadcast and a tf2 broadcast. I implemented and understood most part of it. But I am having a hard time distinguishing between the two in terms of logic. I want to know how are the two different and where to use which one?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324820/what-is-the-difference-between-a-tf2-static-broadcast-and-tf2-broadcast?/) by [harrykarwasra](https://answers.ros.org/users/42084/harrykarwasra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Static transforms are transforms that are assumed not to change -- or *very* infrequently.

Because of that, they don't need to be periodically broadcasted. At the implementation level, this means static transform broadcasters can make use of [topic latching](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Publisher_Options), greatly reducing required message traffic on the TF topics.

For transforms that do change, this is not suitable, so that's where a regular TF broadcaster comes in.

If you look at the two tutorials you mention, you'll see that the static broadcaster essentially calls `sendTransform(..)` *once* and then the programs hangs in the `ros::spin()`.

The non-static broadcaster calls `sendTransform(..)` at the end of the `poseCallback(..)`, which is called for every incoming `turtlesim::Pose` message. This essentially means that `sendTransform(..)` will be called at a specific rate, which would make sense as the transform needs to be updated for every new pose.

Finally: regular broadcasters publish to `/tf`, while static broadcasters publish to `/tf_static`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8